# How would one go about making a directory (mkdir) in python with kivy on android(buildozer)?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

So im trying to simply just trying to make a directory with kivy and i simply cant get it to work. I a useing the os.mkdir() function.

I have tried to just simply `os.mkdir("a")`, but i couldnt find any directory named a (after doing a full phone search, with the phone plugged in to my pc).
I have alos tried `os.getcwd()` as in `os.mkdir(os.getcwd()+"a")`, but to no avail.

To put it simply i am lost, can't find anything about it online either... So if you know how i would greatly appreciate to be enlightend on the subject, thx in advance.

And i am importing os, also tried to run `os.mkdir` before importing kivy.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the same directory as the current working directory of your program? Call `os.getcwd()` again and check the directory which is returned.

Comment: os.getcwd() returns /data/data/org.test.testpack/files/app
but i cant find that directory no my phone, i would like to add images/and also have the ability to change them, but it's difficult when i cant find the folders on the phone (connected to the pc of course)

Comment: Have you tried using `os.chdir()`? That way, you can control the location where the directory is created and, this, where the files are written.

Comment: That kinda seems to insta crash the program...

Thou that might be because i dont know what to set it to, i tried "/data/org.test.testpack/files/app" and just "" but it didnt really want to work... (the app)

Comment: Passing a path to `os.chdir()` sets your current working directory to the path passed. So, if you called `os.chdir("path/to/my/program")` then called `os.mkdir("directory")` will create the directory `"path/to/my/program/directory"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried to just simply io.mkdir("a")

There is no `io.mkdir` - do you mean `os.mkdir`?

The directory will be created inside the current directory of the script, which is a folder inside the app's private directory as defined by Android.

That means you should see your new directory in e.g. `os.listdir(".")`.

Comment: Yeah, the folders show op in os.listdir(".") togeter with p4a_env_vars.tex, main.pyc and others...

But it dosent show up on the phone... or rather not the pc...

Comment: It sounds like it's working fine, but you're misunderstanding some other part of your toolchain. For instance, why would it show up on the PC, and in what context? And you've already proven that it does show up on the phone, so why do you say it doesn't?

Comment: Well, i plugged my power cable in my phone and allowed file trasnfer, so i am looking at my phone thru my pc, but i cant find any of the things listed from os.listdir("."), not when i am looking at my phones file manager either, but i can see the save data from other apps... i want to be able to acces those created folders, is that not possible?

Comment: The folder you've made your directory in simply isn't a folder accessible to the file manager, although it might be visible over adb. It sounds like you want to save your files in the external storage directory, see https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#storage-paths